# POST Request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've task: X company has created Z school, in school there is only one class.
School needs: 1. to create students' list:

a. id
b. name
c. surname
d. birth date
e. addresses
f. scores

How can I post request in node.js to get all these above information? I'm using Firebase and get request is already done. maybe I'm asking question wrongly, cause I'm an amateur and sorry for that.

This is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const { admin } = require('../firebase');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const reference = admin.database().ref('/students')

    reference.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        res.json(snapshot.val())
        reference.off('value')
    }, (errorObject) => {
        res.send(`somethig wrong: ${errorObject.code}`)
    })
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => {

})

module.exports = app
```

Comment: You haven’t tried anything in the post yet

Comment: I know, and I'm asking how can I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to send POST requests through your web application like the following example:

```
axios.post( '/student', { name: 'John', sname: 'Cage' })
     .then( function( resp ) {
       console.log( resp )
     })
     .catch( function( err ) {
       console.error( err )
     })
```

Now you can listen "/student" (the POST request) from your NodeJS server:

```
app.post( '/student', (req, res) => {
  // Your new student data
  console.log( 'Name:', req.body.name )
  console.log( 'Surname:', req.body.sname )
})
```